# Attempting to Real Time Plot sensor data from an Arduino

Tags: matlab, arduino, real-time

I am working on a project where I am using a dual servo and one sonar hc-sr04 to map things. I am still at beginning stages but am working with simple stuff like mapping a box. I am currently taking the arduino serial data where I have (R,theta, phi) and turning that to (x,y,z) and then plotting on matlab. After a full scan I would upload the txt file to matlab and run it. I want this to be real time. 
This is my arduino code

```
#include <Servo.h>
#include <NewPing.h>
Servo myservo,myservo2;  // create servo object to control a servo
#define TRIGGER_PIN 7
#define ECHO_PIN 2
#define MAX_DISTANCE 200
NewPing s1(TRIGGER_PIN,ECHO_PIN,MAX_DISTANCE);
double smoothedValue1,smoothedValue2;
float filterValue; 
const int numReadings = 100;

int readings[numReadings];      // the readings from the analog input
int readIndex = 0;              // the index of the current reading
int total = 0;                  // the running total
int average = 0;                // the average
int myCounter = 0;
int Counter = 0;
int upper=2;
// twelve servo objects can be created on most boards

int pos = 0;    // variable to store the servo position

void setup() {
  myservo.attach(12); // attaches the servo on pin 9 to the servo object
  myservo2.attach(11);
  myservo.write(pos);
  myservo2.write(pos);
  for (int thisReading = 0; thisReading < numReadings; thisReading++) {
    readings[thisReading] = 0;
  }
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  if(myCounter<182/upper) 
  {
  for (pos = 0; pos <= 180; pos += 1) { // goes from 0 degrees to 180 degrees
    // in steps of 1 degree
    myservo.write(pos);              // tell servo to go to position in variable 'pos'
    delay(15); // waits 15ms for the servo to reach the position
    total = total - readings[readIndex];

   int Input1=s1.ping_cm();
    if (Input1 == 0 || Input1 >100)
         {
          Input1=100;
         }
         readings[readIndex] = Input1;
  // add the reading to the total:
  total = total + readings[readIndex];
  // advance to the next position in the array:
  readIndex = readIndex + 1;

  // if we're at the end of the array...
  if (readIndex >= numReadings) {
    // ...wrap around to the beginning:
    readIndex = 0;
  }

  // calculate the average:
  filterValue=.2;
  average = total / numReadings;
  smoothedValue1 = (average * (1 - filterValue)) + (smoothedValue1  *  filterValue);
           smoothedValue2 = (smoothedValue1 * (1 - filterValue)) + (smoothedValue2  *  filterValue);
  // send it to the computer as ASCII digits
  // send it to the computer as ASCII digits




Serial.print(smoothedValue2);
Serial.print("\t");
Serial.print(pos);
Serial.print('\t');
Serial.println(Counter);
delay (30);

  }
  for (pos = 180; pos >= 0; pos -= 1) { // goes from 180 degrees to 0 degrees
    myservo.write(pos);              // tell servo to go to position in variable 'pos'
    delay(15); // waits 15ms for the servo to reach the position
    total = total - readings[readIndex];

   int Input1=s1.ping_cm();
    if (Input1 == 0 || Input1 >100)
         {
          Input1=100;
         }
         readings[readIndex] = Input1;
  // add the reading to the total:
  total = total + readings[readIndex];
  // advance to the next position in the array:
  readIndex = readIndex + 1;

  // if we're at the end of the array...
  if (readIndex >= numReadings) {
    // ...wrap around to the beginning:
    readIndex = 0;
  }

  // calculate the average:
  average = total / numReadings;
   filterValue=.2;
          smoothedValue1 = (average * (1 - filterValue)) + (smoothedValue1  *  filterValue);
           smoothedValue2 = (smoothedValue1 * (1 - filterValue)) + (smoothedValue2  *  filterValue);
  // send it to the computer as ASCII digits

Serial.print(smoothedValue2);
Serial.print("\t");
Serial.print(pos);
Serial.print('\t');
Serial.println(Counter);
delay (30);

  }
   myCounter = myCounter + 1;
   Counter=Counter+upper;
   myservo2.write(Counter);
  }

}
```

This is my code. My Matlab code is currently

```
clc;clear;

[A,B,C]=textread('CoolTerm Capture 2016-08-01 13-49-13.asc','','headerlines',6);
[A];
[X]=A.*sind(B).*cosd(C);
[Y]=A.*sind(B).*sind(C);
[Z]=A.*cosd(B);
scatter3(X,Z,Y,3)
```

I know a little about reading com ports and have done a few scenarios but none of them have been real time. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Some things that maybe would help you.

In Matlab you can use `hold all` to plot in the same figure, so that way yo can add points or curves or whatever to your plot. This short routine shows what I'm saying:

```
plot(0,0, '*r');
xlim([0 100]);
ylim([0 100]);
hold all
for x=1:100
    plot(x,x,'*r');
    pause(1)
end
```

On the other hand, for the communication with the arduino you can use the serial port communication available in Matlab and read the Serial data send by the Arduino directly in Matlab. You can find some info [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/getting-started-with-serial-i-o.html).

Your goal has to be to integrate the two parts I mentioned into one code that works with your previous code.

Hope it helps.